# How to tell if a DataRow is dirty

Tags: ado.net

Additional rows appended to a DataTable are returned when the RowStateFilter is DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent, even if they have not been edited by the user.

And the DataTable RowChanged event fires when the DataTable is first populated by a select from the database, before any edits have taken place.

Is there any convenient way to tell if a row is actually dirty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a copy of the original record to compare against and make the is dirty determination at the point you need to know whether it's dirty.

Check the datarow's rowstate property and if Modified compare the values in the Current and Original DataRowVersions.

See the following [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083193/ado-net-dirty-records-in-dataset) which includes code that may give you some pointers on how to implement this.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it would probably involve keeping an image of the original for comparison, but was hoping there was something built in, ValueAsRead, CurrentValue, or perhaps a RowAsReadHashValue, CurrentRowHashValue.